# Pack all tabs in firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

So I'm the kind of people who open a bunch of tabs. But now I'm gonna re-install my OS. So I want to ask is there a method, to save all the tabs I open and then restore it after I re-install the OS? Or maybe have a key that saves all opening tabs to a bookmark folder then I can re-open them?

P.S. The sync function for Firefox isn't what I want. Since it's sync tabs **between** devices, while I'm reinstalling stuff which means it isn't syncing across devices.

Comment: Questions about web browser functionality are off-topic on [webapps.se]. Try [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Save sessions as bookmarks and access them across devices
>   Using Session Sync you can save sessions as bookmarks.
>   Use the rich user interface for session management: create, restore, open, edit or delete sessions/bookmarks or add new tabs to a certain session.

**https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/session-sync/**